# Kodi initial set up for Xcode and running git code on system

Tags: ios, iphone, open-source, kodi

I am just beginning with the set up of Kodi so I need help on this to start. Here is GitHub link on which I am working:

https://github.com/xbmc/xbmc/tree/master

Please help me on this to implement.

Thanks,
Ratneshwar

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful to know what platform you are attempting to set up kodi on so we can help you however i have dropped a easy to follow guide on how to perform the intial setup.

http://www.wirelesshack.org/new-kodi-17-krypton-setup-and-how-to-install-exodus.html

**EDIT:** After reading your question more i notice you mention Xcode which implies IOS device. Below will describe how to install kodi with both Xcode and Cydia Impactor.

Below instructions come from https://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/iosapps/how-install-kodi-on-iphone-or-ipad-without-jailbreaking-3634908/ I have tested both methods and can confirm they work.

**Cydia Impactor**

you'll require the latest kodi .ipa file (these are easily found on the internet) e.g. https://mega.nz/#!ojghwCDI!HnQx6lhzxoeRRxchyLlrrINGW8ISZodDbg20uOIgegE

1. Connect your iPhone or iPad to your PC or Mac. If iTunes opens automatically when you plug in your iOS device, make sure you close it before you go any further.
2. Open Cydia Impactor and drag-and-drop the Kodi IPA file you downloaded earlier on to the app. (download Cydia Impactor here: http://www.cydiaimpactor.com/)
3. Make sure your iOS device is selected in the drop-down menu, and click Start.
4. Cydia Impactor will ask for an Apple ID login. It's verified with Apple, and is only used to sign the IPA file, but you can use an alternative Apple ID if privacy is a concern.
5. Once the app has been installed, head to Settings > General > Profiles & Device Management (this may vary slightly depending on your version of iOS), find the profile with your Apple ID and open it.
6. Tap the Trust button to 'trust' the new Kodi app on your iPhone or iPad.
7. Open the app and enjoy the many benefits available to users of Kodi!

**Xcode**

You'll require 3 things before beginning

1. Kodi deb file available here (https://kodi.tv/download)
2. IOS app signer available here (http://dantheman827.github.io/ios-app-signer/)
3. Xcode available here (https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?mt=12)

Once this is done follow the steps below

1. Plug your iPad or iPhone into your Mac and open Xcode.
2. Select 'Create a new Xcode project'. Make sure Application is highlighted in the iOS section on the left, and then click on Single View Application. Hit Next.
   [image]
3. In the next dialogue box you need to identify the application you're creating. Fill in Product Name (we'd suggest Kodi) and Organisation Identifier (which should be something unique - I went with com.DavidPrice). The other fields should be filled in already, and you can leave the options as they are. You could choose to make the app specifically iPad or iPhone at this point but we might as well leave it as Universal. Hit Next.
   [image]
4. On the next box, choose a location for your Git repository. We just saved it on the desktop
5. Don't allow Xcode to access your contacts. Or do, if you want. We said no, but we don't think it makes a difference.
6. In the middle of the Xcode screen you'll see an unobtrusive error message: 'No code signing identities found'. Click Fix Issue underneath this message, then Add… on the next dialogue box. Enter your Apple ID and sign in.
   [image]
7. Go back to the main screen and you'll see a message: "To fix this issue, select a Development Team to use for provisioning". There should only be one 'Development Team' to choose from, so go ahead and click Choose. Xcode will say it's resolving the issues, and after a short wait everything should be fixed.
   [image]
8. Open App Signer - just double-click the icon that you saved to your desktop when you unzipped the download. Where it says Input File, you want the Kodi deb file we downloaded earlier: click Browse, find the file on your desktop (or wherever else you saved it) and click Open.
   Signing Certificate should be filled in already (this should contain your Apple ID); for Provisioning Profile, select the profile with the identifier we set in step 3. New Application ID will be filled in, but we added Kodi as an App Display Name (this is what will appear on your Home screen). Click Start.
   [image]
9. Choose a file name for the Save As field - again, you can just go with the suggestion, provided you'll be able to remember it - and a location. Click Save. App Signer will unpack the data and save the file; it'll say Done (at the bottom of the tab - you don't get a separate message) when it's finished.
10. We're nearly there. Go back into Xcode and select Window > Devices. Click on your iOS device in the lefthand pane. At the bottom of the righthand pane containing your iPhone or iPad's details - you may have to scroll down to see it - is a small plus sign. Click this. (There's a plus sign at the bottom of the lefthand pane too, and this is more easily visible. But you want the one on the right.)
    Find and select the .ipa file that iOS App Signer generated in step 9, and click Open. After a short pause while it installs the app (maybe 10-15 seconds in our experience) you'll see the Kodi app listed under Installed Apps.
    [image]
11. Unplug your iOS device and unlock it. You'll see the Kodi icon in the first available space on your device. Depending on your settings, there's a good chance that you'll get an 'Untrusted Developer' error message when you first tap the icon, and you'll only be able to tap Cancel.
    So tap Cancel (or just don't try to start the app yet), and instead go to Settings > General, and scroll down to, and tap, Device Management (it's near the bottom of the list). Under DEVELOPER APP, tap on the account you used earlier in the process, then on the next screen, tap Trust "[name of account]". Then tap Trust again.
    [image]
12. That's it! Go back to the your Home screen

You can use whatever of the above methods to install Kodi then follow the directions I included in the original post to set up the app once its installed. You can also jailbreak your iOS device for an easier time at installing but i would'nt recommend this.

Due to iOS 11 being a 64x OS Kodi did not work on newer version of iOS for awhile i'm not sure if this has changed but it may still be an issue you should look up